# How Internet Download Manager grabs URL of online videos

Tags: vb.net, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm developing a software which streams videos from vimeo. But, I don't know how to fetch it's direct URL.

Suppose the URL of vimeo video is: http://vimeo.com/78848064
But, IDM captures the direct URL of it as, http://pdl.vimeocdn.com/82070/105/203391355.mp4?token2=1387027682_29600487ac61980514ca8d3d014ea6a4&aksessionid=561c553c97d5676a

So, how is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is one similar software that you might be interested to look into. Internet Video Manager. http://www.ivmindia.com

It uses a python back-end program (***included in the same folder***, named as ***dl.exe***) to extract direct link to youtube, vimeo videos.

Answer (score 0):

Pro accounts have access to their own video files using the new (in beta) API3. If you would like access you can request it at vimeo.com/help/contact.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to access my own videos.. I want to find URL of all videos.. with token id

Comment: If a Plus or PRO user authorizes your app, your app could see their video files. Otherwise the only Vimeo supported option is to use Vimeo's embed codes.

Comment: I solved the problem. I used one of the available open source python code for grabbing direct token based URL from youtube and vimeo.

Comment: Just so you are aware, Vimeo does not support these libraries. The developers have attempted to reverse engineer Vimeo's player structure. There is a good chance that the python code doesn't support all edge cases, and there is an even better chance that it will break at a moments notice.